# A good JS library that creates graphs, utilizes SVG/VML and uses JSON as a dataset

Tags: javascript, json, svg, vml

Any suggestions? I was looking at gRaphael but it was more of a ground up approach. I'd like to have basic or complex examples to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Visualizations](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using gRaphael to create all sorts of graphs over the past two months and can't say enough good things about it.

That being said, if you want to try something else, http://highcharts.com/ may be a good resource.

Comment: I'm aware of gRaphael. It's a good custom SVG solution. I've been messing around with Flot lately and it uses Canvas API but it also utilizes SVG, customized by other users. 

http://djw.webfactional.com/raphlot/types.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used [dojox.charting](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/charting/) in my projects, which uses JSON as a data set, and it has worked well for me. In particular, I used it to create the charts [here](http://www.svgopen.org/2010/papers/45-Developing_a_StatecharttoECMAScript_Compiler_Optimized_for_SVG_User_Interface_Development_for_the_World_Wide_Web/index.html#S4.).